# Preg_replace domain problem

Tags: php, regex

I'm Stuck try to get domain using preg_replace,

i have some list url

- download.adwarebot.com/setup.exe
- athena.vistapages.com/suspended.page/
- prosearchs.com/se/tds/in.cgi?4&group=5&parameter=mail
- freeserials.spb.ru/key/68703.htm

what i want is

- adwarebot.com
- vistapages.com
- prosearchs.com
- spb.ru

any body can help me with `preg_replace` ?

i'm using this http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ for testing :)

Comment: I'm sure there is more elegant solution without regex e.g. [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url)

Comment: http://www.rubular.com/r/21AiYeBsvb - second capture (would be using `preg_match` instead of `preg_replace`)

Comment: It would be very difficult for a script to determine what is and is not a subdomain when it comes to 'double-barreled' TLDs (e.g. `.ac.uk`) without a list of expected TLDs.  knittl's answer compensates for this by having the TLDs listed in the regex.

Comment: Irrelevant but the tool you mention in your question (http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) is quite awesome!

Answer (score 1):

using preg_replace, if the number of TLDs is limited:

```
$urls = array( 'download.adwarebot.com/setup.exe',
  'athena.vistapages.com/suspended.page/',
  'prosearchs.com/se/tds/in.cgi?4&group=5&parameter=mail',
   'freeserials.spb.ru/key/68703.htm' );
$domains = preg_replace('|([^.]*\.(?:com|ru))/', '$1', $urls);
```

matches everything that comes before `.com` or `.ru` which is not a period. (to not match subdomains)

---

You could however use PHPs builtin [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) function to get the host (including subdomain) – use another regex, `substr` or array manipulation to get rid of it:

```
$host = parse_url('http://download.adwarebot.com/setup.exe', PHP_URL_HOST);
if(count($parts = explode('.', $host)) > 2)
  $host = implode('.', array_slice($parts, -2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use a regular expression? Of course it is possible, but using this:

```
foreach($url in $url_list){
  $url_parts = explode('/', $url);
  $domains[] = preg_replace('~(^[^\.]+\.)~i','',$url_parts[0]);
}
$domains = array_unique($domains);
```

will do just fine;

Comment: will need special handling for subdomains (OP wants them stripped)

Answer (score 0):

Following code assumes that every entry is exactly at the beginning of the string:

```
preg_match_all('@^([\w]*\.)?([\w]*\.[\w]*)/@', $list, $m);

// var_dump($m[2]);
```

P.S. But the correct answer is still `parse_url`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a more generic solution:

tested by grep, I don't have php environment, sorry:

```
kent$  echo "download.adwarebot.com/setup.exe
dquote> athena.vistapages.com/suspended.page/
dquote> prosearchs.com/se/tds/in.cgi?4&group=5&parameter=mail
dquote> freeserials.spb.ru/key/68703.htm"|grep -Po '(?<!/)([^\./]+\.[^\./]+)(?=/.+)'
```

output:

```
adwarebot.com
vistapages.com
prosearchs.com
spb.ru
```